# How to use v-lazy on a v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using v-expansion-panels and when it's open load a v-data-table, where always show ALL so sometimes it could be too many data, so I want to add a v-lazy component, how I can add it?

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers"
                                  :style="!$vuetify.breakpoint.mobile ? 'width: 40%' : 'width: 100%'"
                                  :items="item.Data"
                                  :items-per-page="-1"
                                  :no-data-text="i18next.t('General:noHayResultados')"
                                  :footer-props="{
                                  itemsPerPageText: i18next.t('General:itemsperpage'),
                                  itemsPerPageAllText: i18next.t('General:todos')
                                  }">

                        <template v-slot:footer.page-text="{pageStart, pageStop, itemsLength}">
                            {{pageStart}} - {{pageStop}} {{i18next.t('General:de').toLowerCase()}} {{itemsLength}}
                        </template>

                    </v-data-table>`
```

I tried to slice the items in a computed method:

```
lazyItems() {
      return this.items.slice(0, 50);
    },
```

but only loaded 50

Comment: v-lazy keeps the component from loading until it is scrolled into view. But it sounds like you are looking for paged loading, as provided by [v-data-table-server](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/server-side-tables/#server-side-search)?

Comment: No, I want to add a v-lazy to my v-data-table, because my table always shows all, but when an item have a lot information it starts to load veeeeery low

Answer (score 0):

You can follow in [Data table - Server side tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/server-side-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort) to know resolve your problem. Basically, you should have `pageNumber` and `pageSize` (item per page) when you fetch data you filter follow `pageNumber`, `pageSize`. Then, you just get data follow `pageSize`.

Example if pageSize = 10, pageNumber = 1, you get data from 1 to 10, and  pageSize = 10, pageNumber = 2, you get data from 11 to 20, not all.